# React: InvalidStateError when trying to create a Media Element Source from an Audio element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm using React v17.0.1.

In one component, **component A**, I have an Audio element. The JSX looks like:

```
<audio ref={handleAudioRef} hidden={true} preload="auto" id={`audio-ref-id-${pk}`} key={pk}>
  <source src={audio} />
</audio>
```

where **handleAudioRef**  looks like:

```
 const handleAudioRef = (r) => {
      audioRef.current = r;
  }
```

Note that **audioRef** is a *context* initiated as audioRef = *useRef(null);*

In another component, I would like to access this same audio element and attach an [Analyzer Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API) to it.

So I've tried the following in **component B**:

```
    const audioCtx =  new AudioContext();
    const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
    const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioRef.current);
```

Note the audioRef is the same *context* as in **Component A**, but I get the following error:

> InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': HTMLMediaElement already connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode. how to obtain media element source node

Now I understand this is a long standing issue, [see here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429204). But I'm wondering in React specifically, what the best workaround might be (if any).

My assumption is that at some point, React/Javascript creats a *MediaElementSourceNode* off the original Audio element and it exists somewhere in Javascript-land. Is there any way I can get access to this *MediaElementSourceNode* That was created? Or is there a better way entirely to go about doing this?

If possible I would like to keep **component A** using an *Audio element* and not re-write it using an *AudioContext*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a solution posted on SO to this problem. But asked in a different context. I lost the original link to the solution.
But it comes down to the *createMediaElementSource* needing to be declared after the *audioRef* event *canplaythrough* It doesn't matter if the media element is rendered in a different component.

As in:

```
audioRef.current.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(){ 
  const audioCtx =  new AudioContext();
  const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioRef.current);
}
```